# set interval on json call to reload new image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set interval that will reload new image from Flickr API.

What do I need to add in order for the page to grab new image using `setInterval`.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);

        var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");
        $('.main').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, in case it takes longer than [interval] seconds to fetch the image due to network latency.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var INTERVAL_IN_MS = 1000; // wait 1 second

  function getImage() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
      }, function(data) {
           var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);
           var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");
           $('.main').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");

        // start the timeout countdown only after the previous image has been fetched and displayed
        window.setTimeout(getImage, INTERVAL_IN_MS);
      });
  }

  window.setTimeout(getImage, INTERVAL_IN_MS);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load a different random image at a set interval?

I think this should work for you:

```
var loadNewImage = function() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);
  var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");
  $('.main').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");
}

setInterval(loadNewImage(), 3000);
```

This will set a new background-image every 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds), so you may want to change the interval time, or connect it with a var at the top that you can easily change if you want to:

```
var imageInterval = 10000;
setInterval(loadNewImage(), imageInterval);
```

Comment: use `loadNewImage` instead of `loadNewImage()` as the first argument to `setInterval`.  `loadNewImage()` executes that function and uses its return value (which is undefined in this case) as the first argument to `setInterval`, which is incorrect.

Comment: getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var for the line var loadNewImage = function()

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting an error like that. Can you paste your code?